# Java, Use BiFunction for a getter with parm

Tags: java, function

I am trying to invoke the method getValueFromMap which takes in a parm and returns a value. I think I need to use a bifunction for this?
I already have something that can invoke a method with no parm for getId and return a value via a Function. How Can I do this?

MyObject

```
public class MyObject{
private String id;
private HashMap<String, String> map;

public String getId(){
return id;
}

public String getValueFromMap(String key){
return map.get(key)
}

}
```

My ReadFunction.java

```
public interface ReadFunction<R , T> {
T readValue(R object);

class Impl<R, T>
    implements ReadFunction<R, T> {

    private final Function<R, T> function;

    public Impl(final Function<R, T> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    @Override
    public T readValue(final R object) {
        return this.function.apply(object);
    }
}
```

How I create an invoke a read function

```
    ReadFunction<MyObject, String> ID_READ_FUNC = new ReadFunction.Impl<>(
    MyObject::getId);
    MyObject object = new MyObject()
    String id = ID_READ_FUNC.readValue(object)
```

How can I define a create and invoke a read function that accepts a value as a parm? I would like to define the parm as part of the ReadFunction itself instead of supplying it to readValue method in interface

I would essentially like to do something like this but instead have the "key" part of the method be defined as part of the constructor

```
ReadFunction<MyObject, String> MAP_VALUE_READ_FNC = new ReadFunction.Impl<>(
        (myObject) -> myObject.getValueFromMap("key"))
```

Comment: `function.apply(object)`?

Comment: Why can't you just get a value from a map?

Comment: A `BiFunction` is a function that takes *two* parameters. Since there are no methods that take two parameters in your example, `BiFunction` does not seem to be what you need to use here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear why you need this pattern and what your are trying to achieve by having a retrieval function an example of what you want to achieve might be the following:

```java
public class MapReadFunction implements Function<Map<String, String>, String> {

    private final Supplier<String> keySupplier;

    public MapReadFunction(Supplier<String> keySupplier) {
        this.keySupplier = keySupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(Map<String, String> map) {
        return map.get(keySupplier.get());
    }
}
```

You can enforce the key supplier to be passed through the constructor and then simply use the `apply` method to accept a map and retrieve the value based on the key. An example usage would be:

```
var object = new MyObject();
var someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
var value = new MapReadFunction(object::getId).apply(someMap);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I edited the class and how I invoke the read function in my OP to hopefully make things clearer. It is important I define the "key" needed for the map to be a part of the ReadFunction definition, and not as a part of readFunction.readValue()

Comment: Well, the above example does that exact thing, as the key supplier is passed in through the constructor.

Comment: So your example defines utilises map.get. What I actually want to utilise is MyObject.getFromMap. Without hardcoding the method inside the actual function, same as how the read function I already have works

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would integrate that into My ReadFunction? I need to do ReadFunction.readValue, not MapReadFunction.apply

Comment: Added another edit that should hopefully make my intentions more clear

Comment: Just rename the example class to `ReadFunction`.